# Can I write process statement in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am wondering if I can write process statement in a LINQ To SQL update method.

data tier:

```
public Boolean Update(int userId,string version, Action<Application> callback)
{
    using (var dc = new VettingDataContext(_connString))
    {
        var entity = (from a in dc.Applications
                      where a.UserId == userId && a.chr_Version==version
                     select a).First();
        callback(entity);
        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

domain tier:

```
ApplicationDAL dal = new ApplicationDAL();
dal.Update(userId, "mf001", info =>
{
     if(...){
      .....
     }else{
     ....
     }

 info.id=Convert.ToInt32(tb_id.Text);
});
```

I'm not sure if those process statements (if..else, and data convert function) work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be ok

Did you try it?  What is the real question?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It doesn't work before, I guess might be some other problems. Thanks.